# How to use the Progressbar with value += in a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

i want to create a progressbar. I set the value of the progressbar += a value (like +=5). At the start the value = 0.

The XAML code.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pgbStatus" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
```

I want to set the value of the progressbar like this:

```
pgbStatus.Value += 10;
```

In the method are many rows like this to set the value up.

But if i start the programm the progressbar shows me the 0 value (=empty)and at the end the 100 value (=full).

Why the progressbar doesnt show me the steps between?

My Method looks like (if the messagebox shows up, the progressbar shows 100 =full):

```
public void Method() {
    //do something
    pgbStatus.Value += 10;
    //do something
    pgbStatus.Value += 10;
    //do something
    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
    pgbStatus.Value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a little code. Is your code runing from a user comand (like a button pressed)? If so, is it runing from other thread? if you run the code from the same thread as the UI, the UI will be frozen until your code finishes execution

Comment: As I said, you have to run from other thread. I can't formulate a proper answer right now, but search Task.Run for start new threads and you'll also need DataBinding to comunicate the values between the UI thread and your code thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one more answer won't hurt...

In the button click handler, run your "Method" on another thread. When you need to update the progress bar, use it's Dispatcher to increase the value (the dispatcher runs the code on the UI thread).

Click event handler:

```
private async void btnMethod_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbStatus.Value = 0;
    await Task.Run((Action)Method);
    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
    pgbStatus.Value = 0;
}
```

And the updated method, Method:

```
public void Method()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // do something
    pgbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pgbStatus.Value += 10);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // do something
    pgbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pgbStatus.Value += 10);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // do something
    pgbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pgbStatus.Value += 60);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // do something
    pgbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pgbStatus.Value += 10);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // do something
    pgbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pgbStatus.Value += 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ui thread is not getting time to update the UI, so You need to give time to UI thread for UI updation. For this you have to do your work in async manner. YOu can use await and async. I have update your method as below:

```
    public async void Method()
    {
        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        //do something
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pgbStatus.Value += 10;

        MessageBox.Show("Finished");
        pgbStatus.Value = 0;
    }
```

Instead of Task.delay(1000) you can put your code

Answer (score 1):

First, we'll need to create a DataBinding. In the xaml:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pgbStatus" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Path=ProgBarValue}"/>
```

Now we create a class for the binding:

```
public class AuxBindings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AuxBindings()
    {
        ProgBarValue=0;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private int progBarValue;
    public int ProgBarValue
    {
        get
        {
            return progBarValue;
        }
        set
        {
            progBarValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code behind from your main windows, we associate a instance of the class with the binding:

```
AuxBindings a = new AuxBindings();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pgbStatus.DataContext=a;
}
```

Now all we have to do is create a new thread for the execution, and all the value modification you need to do, you just have to change the value of the property:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(()=>
        {
            Method();
        }
    );
}

public void Method() {
    //do something
    a.progBarValue += 10;
    //do something
    a.progBarValue += 10;
    //do something
    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
    a.progBarValue = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When program is running, this will be perform on one tread.
For resolving this, you should use of a global int variable for saving progress percent anytime (Like `int percent = 0`) and update it during your code.

Then, you should use a timer (Like `Timer MyTimer`) that updates progress value in specified intervals (for example every 100 ms) and in each interval, use this: (Put it in `MyTimer_Tick` event)

```
progressbar.Value = percent.
if(percent>=100)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
    MyTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

By this, program runs two thread and updates progress value.

Do this and see result.

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: And where i get that in? in the method? And how i set the timer to 100ms?

Comment: In Timer_Tick event put above code. And during your code, update percent variable (like `percent = 10;` or `percent = 25;`). You must active timer in the first of your code (like: `Mytimer.Enabled=true`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Misc_controls.ProgressBarTaskOnUiThread"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ProgressBarTaskOnUiThread" Height="100" Width="300"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
<Grid Margin="20">
    <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="pbStatus" />
</Grid>
```

```
            private void This_is_Your_Button_Click_EVENT(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
                    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

                    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
            }

            void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                    pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }
```

Comment: Or you can use 
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75" />  only on XAML side
I am not sure for this.

Comment: Is your progress start as soon as Page load?

Comment: No, if i click a button the progress should start